# Using Windows clipboard

Tags: c#, wpf, google-chrome, clipboard

I am maintaining a WPF .NET application, and a user got a crash on trying to copy from a DataGrid control. I googled, and found that the reason for this was that some other application he was using probably did not call `CloseClipboard()`. Excel also gave an error message in the same situation, with the message 'We couldn't free up space on the Clipboard. Another program might be using it right now.'

I then wrote another program that has a button to Open/Close the clipboard, and then I could reproduce this behaviour, and I implemented the same 'fix' with just an error message.

However, out of curiousity, I wanted to see how Google Chrome handled the issue. I locked the clipboard using my program, and confirmed that Excel was complaining. But still, Chrome handled copy/paste gracefully. I could copy from Chrome and into notepad, but not to/from notepad and Excel. And funny enough, I can actually copy from notepad to Chrome.

I have been browsing the source code of Chromium, but I can't find the implementation of the copy/paste logic. Does anyone know how Chrome handles this?

And how is it possible that I can't copy/paste within notepad, but from notepad to Chrome works fine?

In all implementations I can find online, the solution seems to be the same as I got right now: To try a few times over a second or so, before giving up.

For reference, this is the code behind for my clipboard locker:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ClipboardLocker
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetOpenClipboardWindow();

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool OpenClipboard(IntPtr hWndNewOwner);

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool CloseClipboard();

        bool clipboardLocked = false;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            double screenWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
            double screenHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
            double windowWidth = this.Width;
            double windowHeight = this.Height;
            this.Left = (screenWidth / 2) - (windowWidth / 2);
            this.Top = (screenHeight / 2) - (windowHeight / 2);
        }

        private void LockButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!clipboardLocked)
            {
                IntPtr handle = GetOpenClipboardWindow();
                OpenClipboard(handle);
                clipboardLocked = true;
                LockButton.Content = "Unlock";
            }
            else
            {
                CloseClipboard();
                clipboardLocked = false;
                LockButton.Content = "Lock";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[UPDATE]

After some more experimentation, it seems that Chrome is able to unlock the clipboard somehow. After I have done a copy/paste in Chrome, it works in other applications as well. How can Chromw 'steal' the clipboard from my locker-program?
MSDN mentioins `ChangeClipboardChain`. I will try and experiment with that.

Comment: Have you tested using the WinForms clipboard classes (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx) and seeing if they behave any differently? No idea if it will, just a thought.

Comment: @Yushatak Yes, The WinForms clipboard methods use the 'try a few times'-loop, while the WPF clipboard methods does not, and just throws the exception right away. No other difference as far as I can tell.

Comment: Looks like CloseClipboard takes no arguments, so perhaps where you handle that exception try calling CloseClipboard and try again?

Comment: @Yushatak That was my first hope, but it didn't do anything, as far as I can tell. Also, see my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take over the clipboard, I first call `OpenClipboard` with a `NULL` argument. This 'steals' the clipboard from whatever window currently holds it. I then close it by calling `CloseClipboard`. This will now work because the clipboard will be 'the open clipboard is associated with the current task' as MSDN puts it.

Now that the clipboard is closed properly, calling either WPF's or Windows Forms' `Clipboard.SetText()` works.

This is certainly not a very good solution, but I believe it is the best option Windows gives us in this case.

Here is my `ClipboardHelper`, if someone else faces this issue.

```cs
static class ClipboardHelper
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetOpenClipboardWindow();

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool OpenClipboard(IntPtr hWndNewOwner);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool CloseClipboard();

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool ChangeClipboardChain(IntPtr hWndRemove, IntPtr hWndNewNext);

    public static bool SetText(string text)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = GetOpenClipboardWindow(); // Gets the HWND of the window that currently owns the clipboard

        if (hWnd == null)   // If no window currently owns the clipboard, just go ahead and set the text.
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(text);
        }
        else
        {
            OpenClipboard(IntPtr.Zero);
            CloseClipboard();
            System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(text);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your data to a JSON file instead of the clipboard. By this reason you can access values even the program will be closed.

Comment: I assumed he wasn't using it as data storage, but rather needed clipboard support specifically?

Comment: Yes, the use case is copy/paste between my application and excel.